# PATH not getting included in startup script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am trying to add the path to the compiler to the $PATH variable. To do this I add the line

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:actualpathhere"
```

to the `~/.bash_profile` file. Now when I open  another terminal and try to build my code it doesnt work. If I do `echo $PATH` in the new terminal it doesnt show the correct path. I am confused as to why this is happening. I use a Mac (Snow leopard) and the terminal uses bash.

Comment: did you try running : source .bash_profile?

Comment: yes it says command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter the line in your `bash_profile`, there should be no `$` before the `export`.

> <s>$</s> `export PATH="$PATH:actualpathhere"`

This alone would be correct:

```
export PATH="$PATH:actualpathhere"
```

`$` designates the prompt from the shell itself, so in some online tutorials you will find it in front of commands that you should manually enter. You will however never have to enter the `$`.

---

Going with `bash_profile` on OS X is okay, because [it is loaded](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) whenever a Terminal window is opened. This isn't really the case for other operating systems or terminals, so it'd be possible to put the variables into `~/.bashrc` and call `source ~/.bash_profile` from there.